# QGIS 3.6 not responding

Tags: qgis, installation

I just installed QGIS 3.6 64bit on a Windows 10 machine. I cannot get it to load. The splash screen hovers for some time before the main window starts to show. But the main window stops as a white box and it goes no further.

Any ideas? This is a new machine and QGIS has never been installed before.

Best to just go back and try an earlier version?

Comment: 3.4.5 installed, however whilst it loads and appears usable, its extremely slow to do anything!

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Comment: This sounds more like an issue with your hardware or drivers/os. Is QGIS the only software running slow on your new machine? Also dont forget to remove settings in `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3` before trying another version. After that I'd try updating drivers and checking hardware (you will find tools for this using google). Or follow underdarks suggestion if you are convinced it is not your machine.